# Git - branch present on list but not found to delete

Tags: git, git-branch

I have an old branch presence on git branch list, but I do not able to remove it using:

```
git branch -D hotfix/my_old_branch

error: branch 'hotfix/my_old_branch' not found.
```

Trying to `git push origin :hotfix/my_old_branch`

> error: unable to delete 'hotfix/my_old_branch': remote ref does not
>   exist

Any idea?

EDIT:

`git branch` ... the branch appears on list

```
$ git branch      
* Dev
  Pro
  Test
  hotfix/my_old_branch
  master
```

`git branch -D hotfix/my_old_branch` ...

> error: branch 'hotfix/my_old_branch' not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: `git push origin :hotfix/my_old_branch` to delete it remotely.

Comment: not works, how I said.

Comment: It is not a duplicate: "branch not  found". Plese, see my edit.

Comment: Can you show the output of `git branch`?

Comment: Yes,  just edited.

Comment: One possibility is that a non-visible character is part of the name. Check the .git/refs folder and dig through it, can you see anything out of place with regards to that name in there?

Comment: On .git/refs/heads, cited  branch not exists.